# Load aspx into a div: wrong path

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a page that I want to load into a div.

[image]

I am found at Trial.js:

```
$('#mydiv').load('../Views/Employer/Tracking.aspx');
```

but the div is not loaded.

What is my problem?

thanks.

Comment: this is jquery syntax, have you included the jquery.js library? please post your post-rendered html code

Comment: also keep in mind that aspx pages are serverside pages, you cannot load them from client side because they need to be compiled on the server

Comment: @Banana You absolutely can load an aspx page like this. The server will render the HTML just as if you went to that page directly. That's kind of the whole point of server languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path to a file will be relative to the current path of the page you're on, not to the javascript file. Make sure your relative path is positioned from there, or use an absolute path.

Since this is MVC, your current "page" may or may not be a page, but from the browser's perspective, whatever "directory" you're in will be what it uses to determine the path.

For example, if your current page is:

```
http://example.com/Marketing/Home/Index
```

then `../Views/Employer/Tracking.aspx` will think that your directory is "Home", and will try to get `http://example.com/Marketing/Views/Employer/Tracking.aspx`, and it should work (**EDIT**: This won't work either, because "Areas" is missing). If however, your current page is

```
http://example.com/Marketing/Home/Index/34
```

then it will think "Index" is your directory, and the relative path will return `http://example.com/Marketing/Home/Index/Views/Employer/Tracking.aspx`, which will not exist.

One solution that will work globally would be to define the URL on the server-side markup into a javascript variable, then use that variable in your js file. For example, in your layout/master page will assign the relative path to a global variable, and it will always build this URL properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _trackingUrl = "<%= Url.Content("~/Areas/Marketing/Views/Employer/Tracker.aspx") %>";
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! it solved my problem.. my path was: ..../employer/product so I change the load: load('tracking.aspx')